# MQTT: Client publishing but subscribers not getting data with QoS 2

Tags: python, c, mqtt, paho, qos

Raspberry Pi 3B+, W10 x64, Paho, Mosquitto MQTT

I have data being sent in 358.4 Kb payloads once a second via MQTT from a Raspberry Pi to a W10 x64 machine. I'm getting the following with different QoS values,

QoS 0: most of the data but some payloads missing, different sent & recieved counts.

QoS 1: most of the data but some payloads missing, different sent & recieved counts.

QoS 2: publisher claims to have sent everything even though the subscriber is recieving nothing. I have a running message at both ends showing the number of sent & recieved in real time.

Anyone know why this is happening?

The publisher side is in C & relevent code snippets below,

```
#include "../daqhats/examples/c/daqhats_utils.h"
// Whole load of includes here
#include "MQTTClient.h"

#define MQTT_ADDRSS "tcp://localhost:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "ExampleClientPub"
#define TOPIC       "mqtt_test"
#define QOS         2
#define TIMEOUT     1000L 

int pub_count = 0;

int publish(MQTTClient client, 
            MQTTClient_deliveryToken token, 
            MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts, 
            char* payload,
            int device)
{
    int rc = 0;
    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    int payload_len = 25600 * sizeof(double);
    MQTTClient_publish(client, TOPIC, payload_len, &payload, QOS, 0, &token);
    printf("Published: %d\n", device);
    pub_count++;
    
    return rc;
}
        

int main(void)
{
    // MQTT initialzers
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    MQTTClient_create(&client, MQTT_ADDRSS, CLIENTID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    union DAQ_Data{
        double f[2 * 25600];
        char   s[2 * 25600 * sizeof(double)];
    };

    
   // A whole load of DAQ hardware set up here


    union DAQ_Data payload;
    
    do //while (is_running)
    {
        for (device = 0; device < DEVICE_COUNT; device++)
        {
            // Read data
            result = mcc172_a_in_scan_read(address[device], &scan_status[device], samples_to_read,
                                           timeout, payload.f, buffer_size, 
                                           &samples_read[device]);
                                           
            publish(client, token, conn_opts, payload.s, device);
            
            // More DAQ stuff
        }


        fflush(stdout);
        
        usleep(100000);
        

        if (enter_press())
        {
            printf("Aborted - enter pressed\n\n");
            break;
        }

    }
    while (!enter_press());
 
    printf("Pub count: %d\n", pub_count);
    sleep(2);

    // DAQ hardware clean up

    return 0;
}
```

The PC subscriber side in Python, taken fromm the Eclipse MQTT Client example,

```
import argparse
import os
import ssl
import sys

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', required=False, default="192.168.30.212")#"mqtt.eclipseprojects.io")
parser.add_argument('-t', '--topic', required=False, default="mqtt_test") #"$SYS/#")
parser.add_argument('-q', '--qos', required=False, type=int, default=2)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--clientid', required=False, default=None)
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', required=False, default=None)
parser.add_argument('-d', '--disable-clean-session', action='store_true', help="disable 'clean session' (sub + msgs not cleared when client disconnects)")
parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', required=False, default=None)
parser.add_argument('-P', '--port', required=False, type=int, default=None, help='Defaults to 8883 for TLS or 1883 for non-TLS')
parser.add_argument('-k', '--keepalive', required=False, type=int, default=60)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--use-tls', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--insecure', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-F', '--cacerts', required=False, default=None)
parser.add_argument('--tls-version', required=False, default=None, help='TLS protocol version, can be one of tlsv1.2 tlsv1.1 or tlsv1\n')
parser.add_argument('-D', '--debug', action='store_true')

args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

mq = open("mq_test.bin", "wb")
rec_count = 0

def on_connect(mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
    print("rc: " + str(rc))


def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    
    global rec_count  
    rec_count = rec_count + 1
    # message = msg.payload.decode("utf-8") + '\n'
    mq.write(msg.payload)
    print("recieved: ", rec_count)


def on_publish(mqttc, obj, mid):
    print("mid: " + str(mid))


def on_subscribe(mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))


def on_log(mqttc, obj, level, string):
    print(string)

usetls = args.use_tls

if args.cacerts:
    usetls = True

port = args.port    
if port is None:
    if usetls:
        port = 8883
    else:
        port = 1883

mqttc = mqtt.Client(args.clientid,clean_session = not args.disable_clean_session)

if usetls:
    if args.tls_version == "tlsv1.2":
       tlsVersion = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
    elif args.tls_version == "tlsv1.1":
       tlsVersion = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1
    elif args.tls_version == "tlsv1":
       tlsVersion = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
    elif args.tls_version is None:
       tlsVersion = None
    else:
       print ("Unknown TLS version - ignoring")
       tlsVersion = None

    if not args.insecure:
        cert_required = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    else:
        cert_required = ssl.CERT_NONE
        
    mqttc.tls_set(ca_certs=args.cacerts, certfile=None, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=cert_required, tls_version=tlsVersion)

    if args.insecure:
        mqttc.tls_insecure_set(True)

if args.username or args.password:
    mqttc.username_pw_set(args.username, args.password)

mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_publish = on_publish
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

if args.debug:
    mqttc.on_log = on_log

print("Connecting to "+args.host+" port: "+str(port))
mqttc.connect(args.host, port, args.keepalive)
mqttc.subscribe(args.topic, args.qos)

mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Just to be clear have you checked with a different client e.g. mosquitto_sub? Also I'd love the call to subscribe to the `on_connect()` callback

Comment: You are calling `MQTTClient_connect` prior to every publish. I've taken a quick look at the code and it does not look like this checks for an existing connection i.e. always establishes a connection (but I may have missed something!). Try wrapping this in a `MQTTClient_isConnected(client)`. Agree with Hardillb that the first step is to confirm if the issue is with the publisher or subscriber.

Comment: same issue with different client

Comment: By this I assume you mean that you used a different app (e.g. `mosquitto_sub`) and did not receive all messages (edit question with details). That means, assuming "client" was correctly configured, the issue is with publisher (or, potentially  broker) so see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems and points to note:

1. The MQTT protocol encodes the payload size into the MQTT packet so if only partial data is being sent or received, that is a Malformed Packet and it depends on the client/broker how it handles that.  But the point is that, valid packets received by your Python code are guaranteed to have the correct payload.
2. You are using `loop_forever()` which **calls the callbacks asynchronously** and at the same time you are **writing to `mq` synchronously** - this is guaranteed data loss.  Handle the data in an async manner - write to separate files, use a database, pass off to another process.  Remember that packets aren't even guaranteed to be received in order.

> If you use the loop_start() or loop_forever functions then the loop runs in a separate thread, and it is the loop that processes the incoming and outgoing messages.
>
> In this case the callbacks can occur any time in your script and are asynchronous.

[Source](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-python-callbacks/)

I believe these are the core issues.  Fix those and you should have no more data loss.